# IndexError : list index out of range in python robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am printing a phone_list but it shows index error i even tried range() with len() but still no outcome.

```
def verify_by_phone(self):
    self.cec.SEARCH_RESULTS_PHONE.set_text_in_xpath_locator(self.last_4)
    phone_list = self.cec.SEARCH_RESULTS_PHONE.get_list_of_possible_elements_once_loaded()
    self.LOG(phone_list[0].text)

    for phone in phone_list:
        if self.last_4 in phone.text:
            self.LOG(f"Found {self.last_4} in {phone.text}")
            break
    else:
        raise AssertionError("Not in the list")
```

I tried
for phone in range(len(phone_list)):
but still the same index error

Comment: Hello, range and the keyword 'in', in this case doesn't raise any exception. But this line could raise one if the list is empty (`self.LOG(phone_list[0].text)`). So, I think your problem is more likely about this line.

Comment: Yes you are correct that particular line throws an error but the list is not empty any solutions?

Comment: How do you know that the list is not empty ? Did you print the attribut ?

Comment: How can I get the list other than that? That is the only way I know to fetch the list

Comment: `print(phone_list)` or `self.LOG(phone_list)` will give you the top format to make sure that it's a list and if it is, if the list is not empty